# How to get a Laravel (v5.6.29) project (app) onto the the platform WebFaction (web hosting server)

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, winscp, webfaction

The project is an app that is coded in PHP, HTML, CSS3, Javascript, JQuery, Laravel ORM. I am currently able to run on a platform called XAMMP on my localhost. Currently, I am trying to deploy the app on a web hosting server by the name of "WebFaction"; however, there seems to be a framework error when uploading a Laravel app (has a Laravel MVC framework). I am using a free SFTP & FTP client to transfer my local files to remote servers.

Here are some other resources that I have already attempted; however, I have failed in deploying my app on the web server due to some issues:

1. https://frontiernxt.com/deploying-a-laravel-app-to-webfaction-using-bitbucket
2. https://coderwall.com/p/3cjmia/setting-up-a-laravel-5-4-app-on-webfaction
3. https://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2015-how-to-setup-laravel-5-in-shared-hosting

The 3rd resource is working on hosting a laravel app on CPanel.

*NOTE: I know this isn't the most secure way of doing this method. This is a temporary fix.

[The WinSCP FTP Client Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4xt0.png)

Comment: You should post some error messages you are getting. I am deploying django and python but if I see some output I might help. Been using webfaction for 4 years. Cheers

Comment: You should install a php app and deploy your code into it. Does this help? https://coderwall.com/p/3cjmia/setting-up-a-laravel-5-4-app-on-webfaction